# Changing the footline in Beamer

Tags: beamer

I am trying to do something that should not be too hard, but for some reason I cannot wrap my head around it. Basically, in the footline of my Beamer presentation, I want to display two logos (in the bottom-left and bottom-right corners of the page), and the framenumber (in the middle). Here is my attempt:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}

\title{\textbf{My awesome presentation}}
\author{Name Surname}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
    \hspace*{0.3cm}\raisebox{0.2cm}{\includegraphics[height=0.8cm]{first_image.png}}%
    \hfill%
    \raisebox{0.5cm}{\insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber}%
    \hfill%
    \raisebox{0.3cm}{\includegraphics[height=0.8cm]{second_image.png}}%
    \hspace*{0.3cm}
}


\begin{document}

{
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
}

\begin{frame}{Title}
Blah blah
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Another frame}
Blah blah
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The images are displayed correctly, but the frame number is not in the middle of the page. Of course I can imagine why, since the two images have different widths, but how can I solve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quick workaround: place the images in some environment of a known width, e.g. a `\parbox`, `minipage` or similar.

Off-topic: If you want the title to be bold, use `\setbeamerfont{title}{series=\bfseries}` and don't put formatting instructions in fields like `\author`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}
\setbeamerfont{title}{series=\bfseries}

\title{My awesome presentation}
\author{Name Surname}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
    \hspace*{0.3cm}\parbox{3cm}{\includegraphics[height=0.8cm]{example-image-golden-upright}}%
    \hfill%
    {\insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber}%
    \hfill%
    \parbox{3cm}{\hfill\includegraphics[height=0.8cm]{example-image-golden}}%
    \hspace*{0.3cm}
    \vskip0.3cm
}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title}
Blah blah
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using `\llap` and `\rlap`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}
\setbeamerfont{title}{series=\bfseries}

\title{My awesome presentation}
\author{Name Surname}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
    \hspace*{0.3cm}\rlap{\includegraphics[height=0.8cm]{example-image-golden-upright}}%
    \hfill%
    {\insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber}%
    \hfill%
    \llap{\includegraphics[height=0.8cm]{example-image-golden}}%
    \hspace*{0.3cm}
    \vskip0.3cm}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title}
  Blah blah
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```